# How can I set LibreOffice to use ISO 8601 date format?

Tags: libreoffice, iso, locale, date

I need LibreOffice to use ISO 8601 date format, but it falsely shows MM/DD/YY when it should correctly be showing YYYY-MM-DD.

## To reproduce I do:

Open a new LibreOffice document and choose Insert->Field->Date, this produces a date field in MM/DD/YY format where I need YYYY-MM-DD

My LibreOffice version is:
Version: 6.4.3.2
Build ID: 1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
Locale: da-DK (en_IE.utf8); UI-Language: en-US

My Ubuntu version is:
20.04 LTS

## I tried:

I have set my locale to: LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8 and when I type date in the shell it correctly uses ISO 8601 format, I therefore believe that my environment is configured correctly.

In Tools->Options...-->Language Settings->Languages->Local setting:
I have tried Danish, English (Ireland) and Zulu none of these fix the issue.

I have looked at the other ISO 8601 questions at "Ask Ubuntu" but did not find any solution.

Please let me know how I can configure LibreOffice to use ISO 8601 dates.

Comment: Related: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/158048/how-do-i-change-the-default-datetime-format/ :-(

Comment: See also following bugzilla entry: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46448

Comment: Hmm, there's no en-DK locale definition, the following applies to da_DK: https://opengrok.libreoffice.org/xref/core/i18npool/source/localedata/data/da_DK.xml?r=8453f6e5

Comment: Thanks for the links, maybe I can somehow fix the local it seems to be a XML file [https://opengrok.libreoffice.org/xref/core/i18npool/source/localedata/data/da_DK.xml?r=8453f6e5].

Comment: Indeed I have been struggling with this issue for a while and found the en_DK locale, which apparently does not fixe this issue, so perhaps it needs to be fixed in the source code of LibreOffice, but where?

Comment: Currently, i can't test it myself, but i assume it could be fixed by modifying one of the locale xml definitions. It's not clear to me what locale LO is applying in your case. If the date is MM/DD/YY, it might be en_US (not en_GB or en_IE, since as far as i see, they don't use that pattern). You might proceed by adapting any of the locales you're not using usually (so nothing important will break), and build LO from that modified source. Since i currently can't test it myself, i can't tell if this would work...

Answer (score 1):

Right click the date field, select Edit Fields and then choose the format you require from the drop down list.

[image]

It works the same way across the LO range so clicking on a cell in LO Calc and following the same routine (format cell) will produce the same result.

Comment: Thanks, this is the fix I am currently using, I should have mentioned it in my question. I would however like it to work without this fix, because on my system LibreOffice keeps reverting to the wrong format.

Comment: So currently, it appears there is then no permanent solution for you but I think my answer stands as it might help others in correctly formatting the date field to their requirement if it not obvious to them.

Comment: Ok I have given you a vote, but I think it should be fixable, if nothing else I figure we could make some kind of patch for the code, but then I don't know how to build and deploy LibreOffice, nor where in the code to fix it.